# Why to override a superclass and call it again inside the function?

Tags: java, oop

I am reading a code which is done something like this, and I want to understand why it is doing this:

```
public abstract class Class2 extends Class1 {
  ... 
  @Override
  public ObjectType someFunction() {
    ObjectType var = super.someFunction();
    .... 
    return var; 
  } 
}
```

So the someFunction() method has been overwritten and the someFunction() of the parent is called again inside it. 
Does it make sense to you? What would be the motivation for doing this?

Comment: Well, what's happening in the `....` bit? That's the meat of the question. Basically this code is "adding" the `....` code to `someFunction()`, and the question of why you'd want to do that depends entirely on what's being added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to duplicate the code for the entire overridden method, but you want to change the logic a little bit or if you want to add a little bit of code, then you can call the overridden method and provide additional code.

This prevents duplication of code and logic in subclasses that wish to override a method but retain some behavior.

As yshavit has indicated in a comment, calling the overridden method may be the only way to access data that is `private` in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty usefull when you want to use inheritance properly.

Just imagine that you have a class Person which is composed by a name and a surname and you want to specify the job, like Farmer.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    //... Constructor

    public String getInfos() {
        return this.name + " " + this.surname;
    }
}

class Farmer extends Person {
    //... Constructor

    @Override
    public String getInfos() {
        return super.getInfos() + " is a farmer.";
    }
}


Person p1 = new Person("Name", "Surname");
System.out.println(p1.getInfos());
// Show "name surname"

Person p2 = new Farmer("Name", "Surname");
System.out.println(p2.getInfos());
// Show "name surname is a farmer."
```